# When using immutable.js with react redux is it permissible to have reducer return a record instance instead of an object?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

I am new to react redux as well as use of the immutable.js library. I am wondering if it a bad idea or not to have my reducer return an instance of a Record as opposed to a simple object. The idea being that doing so would allow me to use convenient methods such as merge as opposed to having to write something like.

```
return Object.assign({}, state, updatedState)
```

Is there any compelling reason why one should NOT do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bad idea to return record instance since `Immutable.js` will handle that for you. Your whole *redux tree* will be immutable therefore it will only be changed by its set of operations.

As mentioned [**here**](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingimmutablejs#guaranteed-immutability)

> Data encapsulated in an Immutable.JS object is never mutated. A new copy is always returned.

### **Workflow**

`Immutable.js` makes data [**Persistant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), therefore *previous copies* of the data is available and shares data *via [hash maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) tries and [vector](https://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) tries*.

Therefore there is no requirement to involve a *costly operation* such as cloning the data.

Need to copy the data from the **cache** is minimized which results it in being **way more faster** that the **clone** operation. It avoids *creating new objects* if there is no change in value.

Another thing to note is both `Object.assign` and `spread operator` are shallow operations. Hence, you need to do more modifications for nested operations.

You can check the performance of both [**here**](https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign/#performance)